# How do I make a "global" variable accessible in an external function within React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I have a global file in which I work with global variables which is imported in App.js.

```
import './globals/global.js' // found within App.js
```

Which looks like

```
global.showDebugging = true
global.forceLogin = true
// etc
```

I also have a common file with exported functions that I use throughout my app.

```
import { randomFunctionName } from '../../globals/functions.js'
```

I want to be able to use global variables (from my global.js file) within my common functions.js file without having to pass the global variable into the common functions as args.

For example:

```
import { randomFunctionName } from '../../globals/functions.js'

export class Intro extends React.Component {

   pressSomething = () => {
      randomFunctionName(variable)
   }
}
```

and then inside of the exported function, I refer to a global variable which comes from App.js. The below concept is what I'd ultimately like to achieve:

```
export function randomFunctionName(variable) {
   
   if (global.showDebugging)
       console.log('debugging message')
}
```

Right now I'm doing something very meh, such as:

```
export function randomFunctionName(global, variable) {
    
   if (global.showDebugging)
       console.log('debugging message')
}
```

So how can I access the globals variables in globals.js within my common functions.js file?

Comment: Why not import `global.js` within `functions.js`, just like you import it anywhere else?

Comment: Oddly enough, I thought I had tried that with no results but it's just bad testing. Thanks for the obvious heads up.